# Direct proof of sequential characterization of limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

In my studies of real analysis the proof of sequential characterization of limits is done by contradiction. The statement is $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)$ iff for every sequence $\{x_n\}\subseteq\mathrm{dom}(f)\setminus\{c\}$ such that $\{x_n\}\to c$ then $\{f(x_n)\}\to L$. Typically proving the “if every sequence $\{x_n\}$... then $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=L$” is done by supposing $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)\neq L$. I don’t really like this proof by contradiction so I’m wondering if there’s a better direct proof out there.

Comment: I think it's more common to see the direct proof. The calculation will depend on $f$ but always uses the definition $(\epsilon-\delta)$ definition of $\lim$.

Comment: @Matematleta I don't understand your comment. The OP was asking for a direct proof instead of the usual proof by contradiction. You said "it's more common to see the direct proof": in fact you meant "the proof by contradiction", didn't you?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I have never seen a direct proof.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the collection $\mathscr F$ of *all* sequences, indexed by some set $\Lambda$, that converge to $c$ and are contained in the interval $[c-1,c+1].$ For arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta^{\lambda}>0$ and an integer $N(\lambda)$ such that if $n>N(\lambda)$ then $x_n^\lambda\in (c-\delta^\lambda,c+\delta^{\lambda})\subseteq [c-1,c+1]$ and $f(x_n^{\lambda})\in(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon).$ Then the collection $\mathscr A=\{(c-\delta^\lambda,c+\delta^{\lambda}):\lambda\in \Lambda\}\bigcup [c-1,c+1]\setminus \{c\}$ is an open cover of the compact set $[c-1,c+1].$ It follows that $I=:\bigcap_{\lambda\in \Lambda} (c-\delta^\lambda,c+\delta^{\lambda})$ is an open interval. If $x\in I$, then $x=x_n^\lambda$ for some sequence $x^\lambda$ and so since $x\in I\subseteq (c-\delta^\lambda,c+\delta^{\lambda})$ we have $f(x)\in (L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon).$