# If $x_n\to c$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(c)}{x_n-c}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, derivatives

I have a question as follow

Let $f:\ (a,b)\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be continuous at $c\in(a,b)$. Let $\,\{x_n\}\subset(a,b)\setminus\{c\}\,$ such that $\,x_n\to c$.

Then how can I show that if these limit exist, then
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\,=\,\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(c)}{x_n-c}\ \ ?
\end{align}

I have tried to applied the definition of the limit, but it became difficult to see what to handle. I got impedent in connecting the assumption and the conclusion where I was supposed to find the number $\delta>0$.

My new attempt : since $f$ is continuous at $c$ and $x_n\to c$, we have
\begin{align}
\big|f(x_n)-f(c)\big|&\to0\ \ \text{when }\ n\to\infty
\\ \big|f(x)-f(c)\big|&\to0\ \ \text{when }\ x\to c.
\end{align}
This is where I got stucked.

I don't know if there're something that I missed when I wrote all the definitions out or if there're theorems that I can use. Could anyone help me with some hints ? Thanks.

Comment: [A link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969575) was already given in [your previous (very similar) post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4823904). Did you look at it? It solves your question(s).

Comment: yes I just saw that link, but I don't understand very well the proof in that link

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\,=\,\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(c)}{x_n-c}$$ is possibly not correct.  We should say **if** the left-hand limit exists, **then** so does the right-hand limit, and  they are equal.  But possibly the right-hand limit exists while the left-hand limit doesn't.

Comment: The link says something finer: if *for every* sequence $x_n$ converging to $c$ we have $g(x_n)\to\ell$, then $\lim_cg=\ell.$ (Here, $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$, but it could be any function).

Comment: @GEdgar yes I have added that into my post just then.

Comment: Do you mean to ask about a function which is differentiable at $c$? With the way the question is written, neither of the limits you are interested in are guaranteed to exist

Comment: @AnneBauval I think that claim is a proof that relate to the continuousness. I have just added the assumption of continuousness of $f$ at $x$ into my post, so I guess we don't need to show that fact.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz so I need to add the differentiability into the assumption ?

Comment: You need to reconsider what you are asking about. If $f$ is differentiable at $c$, then the limit on the left exists, and for any sequence $x_n\to c$, the right-hand limit exists and equals the left-hand limit. So that's probably not what you are asking about. If you mean that for *some* sequence $x_n\to c$, the right-hand limit exists, and then you are wondering if that **implies** the left-hand limit exists, that's a potentially interesting question.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz oh I think I got your point. So my querry is just simply that if $f$ is continuous (may be differentiable if needed) at  $c$ and $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence that convergent to $c$, and both above limits exist, then would they are equal ?

Comment: the left limit existing means by definition for any sequence $x_n\to c$, the right-hand limit must exist and equal the left

Comment: @AlexOrtiz I don't see how your conclusion is claimed from the definition

Comment: The Heine and the Cauchy definitions of the limit are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer written in the linked comment is somewhat hard to read. Based on the discussion in the comments of this post, here is what the question boils down to.

Suppose $L\in\mathbb R$, $c\in (a,b)$ and $g\colon (a,b)\setminus \{c\}\to \mathbb R$ is a function such that
$$
\lim_{x\to c} g(x) = L,
$$
meaning that the limit exists and equals $L$. I claim this implies for any sequence $\{x_n\}\subset (a,b)\setminus\{c\}$ such that $x_n\to c$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_n)$ exists and equals $L$.

*Proof.* Let $\{x_n\}\subset(a,b)\setminus\{c\}$ be a sequence such that $x_n\to c$, and let $\epsilon > 0$. By definition of
$$
\lim_{x\to c} g(x) = L,
$$
there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $0<|x-c|<\delta$, then $|g(x)-L|<\epsilon$. Since $x_n\to c$, there exists $N$ so that if $n\ge N$, $0<|x_n-c|<\delta$. For these values of $n\ge N$, we therefore have $|g(x_n)-L|<\epsilon$, which finishes the proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_n) = L$.

Since the sequence $\{x_n\}\subset(a,b)\setminus\{c\}$ was arbitrary, this finishes the proof of the claim.

Now we see why this question has really nothing to do with derivatives, because we can set $g(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ if we were originally studying a function $f\colon(a,b)\to\mathbb R$. The whole problem revolves around understanding the definition of "$\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=L$."

Comment: your arguement is absolutely amazing. I'm now thinking of your previous second hypothesis that if there some $\{x_n\}:\ x_n\to c$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(c)}{x_n-c} $ exists, then would $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} $ exists and equal to the preceeding lim. I think this question is worth to discuss more

Comment: Generally, if there is just one sequence $x_n\to c$ such that $g(x_n)\to L$, then it won't be the case that $g(x)\to L$ as $x\to c$. For the particular case $g(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$, think of $f(x) = |x|$ and a sequence $x_n\to 0$, $x_n>0$ for every $n$. What the other linked answer in the comments above was showing is that if we upgrade to $g(x_n)\to L$ for *every* $x_n\to c$, then it does hold that $g(x)\to L$ as $x\to a$. In that post, the person asking the question wanted a direct proof instead of a proof by contradiction (which is the more common and simpler argument).